# Document detection on scanned image OpenCV

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I use OpenCV for image pre-processing. I need cut only scanned photo, whithout white area.
I use algoritm:

- image_canny <- apply canny edge detector to this channel
- for threshold in bunch_of_increasing_thresholds:
- image_thresholds[threshold] <- apply threshold to this channel
  for each contour found in {image_canny} U image_thresholds:
- Approximate contour with polygons
- if the approximation has four corners and the angles are close to 90 degrees.for find rectangle object on scanned image. But this example not work, if i put my picture in corner of scanner!

Can anybody advise, how i can find this photo on scanned image? any examples, methods?

Comment: it would be better if you share some sample images or some other relevant image.

Comment: Thx for Edit! Of  course i attach samples: [sample1](http://s019.radikal.ru/i632/1409/e3/9b867ca286a7.jpg), [sample2](http://i003.radikal.ru/1409/12/990fc8613b1f.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve your goal. I will give code for OpenCvSharp, it will be similar for plain C++.

1. Try to add some neutral border around your image. For example, you can just add 10-20 pixels of white around your source image. It can create false contours, but still your target part of the image will be not in the corner anymore.

   ```
   Mat img = Cv2.ImRead("test.jpg");
   Mat imgExtended = new Mat(new OpenCvSharp.Size(img.Size().Width + 40, img.Size().Height + 40), MatType.CV_8UC3, Scalar.White);
   OpenCvSharp.Rect roi = new OpenCvSharp.Rect(new OpenCvSharp.Point(20, 20), img.Size());
   img.CopyTo(imgExtended.SubMat(roi));
   img = imgExtended;
   Mat coloredImage = img.Clone();
   Cv2.CvtColor(img, img, ColorConversionCodes.BGR2GRAY);
   OpenCvSharp.Point[][] contours;
   HierarchyIndex[] hierarchy;
   Cv2.Canny(img, result, 80, 150);
   Cv2.FindContours(result, out contours, out hierarchy, RetrievalModes.External, ContourApproximationModes.ApproxSimple);
   ```
2. You have object and practically white background. You can do any thresholding operation, and then take the biggest blob.

**Update.**
In both cases dark line at the top of your image and dark area at the left corner can still be the problem. In this case you can choose the contour with the largest area by the function

```
double Cv2.ContourArea(Point[] Contour);
```

And then try to create bounding box, which will minimize the error.